# Compose Column content becomes unreachable if the size of the TextField increases

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Composable` which has 2 `TextFields` and a `Button` in a `Column`, when the content of the `TextFields` increases, the `Button` at the bottom becomes unreachable.
Is there a way I can make the `Column` scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and automatically remember ScrollState with default parameters use rememberScrollState.

```
val scroll = rememberScrollState(0)
```

You can add the verticalScroll modifier to enable scrolling within the Column.

```
Column(
            modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scroll)
        ) {
...
```

For more [read](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ScrollState) and [this](https://developer.android.google.cn/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?hl=id#5)